# Aligning a Tikz Picture in line with the surrounding Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-chains

I'd like to align a Tikz Picture in line with the surrounding Text. Here is a MWE Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{joinlabel/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
 edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother

 \tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
     every join/.style={->}}

\begin{document}

Text, more text   
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain] {
 \node[on chain] {$0$};
 \node[on chain] {$A$} ;
 \node[on chain, joinlabel={node[above] {$\scriptstyle\varphi$}}] {$B$};
 \node[on chain, joinlabel={node[above] {$\scriptstyle\psi$}}] {$C$};
 \node[on chain] {$0$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
text and more text go here...
\end{document}
```

Here's the Output: 
[image: An Output!]

To make things more explicit: I am looking for a solution that does not change the code much but however lets me make align the TikZ picture in line with the surrounding Tikz.

Code taken from: This code is taken from [here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/pgf-tikz-commutative-diagram/) -- [Stephan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/stefan-kottwitz)'s [TeXamples](http://www.texample.net/).

(I have some very bad work-arounds that I got to know when I posted it on chat. I may compile them and write them up as a CW answer.)

Comment: `text \begin{tikzcd}[baseline=-0.85ex]
0 \arrow{r}{} & A \arrow{r}{\varphi} & B \arrow{r}{\psi} & C \arrow{r}{} & 0
\end{tikzcd} text` compiles well! But, this changes the code drastically. (Credit: [Gonzalo Medina](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/9447/gonzalo-medina) in Chat)

Comment: Have you tried the wrapfig package?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Not yet! I'll check that out. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: You could give a name to a node, say the first zero with `(0)`, and then for the `tikzpicture` options, add a `baseline=(0.base)`. But do you really need tikz for this when you could just do: `\def\To{\mathop{\;\hbox to2.5em{\rightarrowfill}\;}\limits} Text, more text $0\To A \To^\varphi B \To^\psi C \To 0$ text and more text go here\dots \bye`

Comment: @morbusg Yes, your first suggestion solves the problem! And, what are those `\dots \bye` meant for? They fail to compile.  But, yeah, thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @KannappanSampath: sorry, it's a plain-tex macro.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For minimal intervention in general situations like this, use the `baseline` option for `tikzpicture` combined with the coordinate of a node in the diagram.  The simplest thing in this case is to label the first node with `O` (letter O) and use its baseline.  Here is the working code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(O.base),start chain] {
 \node (O) [on chain] {$0$};
 \node[on chain] {$A$};
 \node[on chain, joinlabel={node[above] {$\scriptstyle\varphi$}}] {$B$};
 \node[on chain, joinlabel={node[above] {$\scriptstyle\psi$}}] {$C$};
 \node[on chain] {$0$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Sample output]

However as @percusse points out, for this particular example the nodes are automatically given the names `chain-#` where `#` is the node number.  So real minimal intervention is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(chain-1.base),start chain] {
 \node[on chain] {$0$};
 \node[on chain] {$A$};
 \node[on chain, joinlabel={node[above] {$\scriptstyle\varphi$}}] {$B$};
 \node[on chain, joinlabel={node[above] {$\scriptstyle\psi$}}] {$C$};
 \node[on chain] {$0$}; }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Of course, there are many other ways to make your particular diagram, with or without `tikz`.  One possibility is `\( 0 \longrightarrow A \stackrel{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{\psi}{\longrightarrow} C \longrightarrow 0 \)`:

[image: Sample output]

which has slightly shorter arrows and is thus probably better for an inline case like this (I also prefer the vertical placing of the arrows). `amsmath` has some extensible arrows that could also be used.

Comment: If the chain is not named explicitly, the nodes are named in the order of appearance via `(chain-#)`. Hence instead of `(O)` you can directly use `(chain-1.base)`.

Comment: Excellent.  That is less intervention in this case.