# Vertical alignment of TikZ within text

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a bit of `TikZ` in my text, namely:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document}
    Some text (\tikz{\node[scale=0.5,solid,draw,thick,blue,rectangle,fill=white] {A};}), and some more
  \end{document}
```

This produces the blue rectangle as expected, but it is not aligned with the bottom of the parentheses, which I want.

Is there a simple way to shift an object or even text within a line vertically, while keeping the rest? Or is there some workaround in `TikZ` that might be able to do so?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65932/15925 .  You use the `baseline` option to do this.

Comment: If I use `Some text (\tikz[baseline=(O.base)]{\node (O) [scale=0.5,solid,draw,thick,blue,rectangle,fill=white,minimum height=0.5cm,minimum width=0.5cm] {a};}), (\tikz[baseline=(O.base)]{\node (O) [scale=0.5,solid,draw,thick,blue,rectangle,fill=white] {d};}) and some more` The two blue boxes are not aligned though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit like the Chain Tutorial in the [`pgfmanual`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).  It is best to specify `text height` and `text depth` for the nodes in this case.  For example as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every node/.style={anchor=base,scale=0.5,draw,thick,blue,
text height=1.7ex,text depth=0.3ex, minimum width=1em}}

Some text 
(\tikz[baseline]{\node {a};}), 
(\tikz[baseline]{\node {d};}) 

More demonstration
(\tikz[baseline]{\node {a};}\tikz[baseline]{\node {d};}%
\hbox to 0pt{\hss\tikz{\draw[very thin,red] (0,0) -- (4cm,0);}})  

\end{document}
```

I have specified `anchor=base` for the nodes, so the baseline of the text in these nodes lies on the x-axis.  Then it is sufficient to just pass the plain `baseline` option to `\tikz` for the vertical alignment.

In general, you can set `baseline` to some vertical dimension to shift material

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{every node/.style={anchor=base,draw,thick,blue,
text height=1.7ex,text depth=0.3ex, minimum width=1em,scale=0.5}}

Some text 
\tikz[baseline]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=0.1ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=0.3ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=0.7ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=1ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=2ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=4ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=-0.3ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=-0.5ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=-1ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=-2.5ex]{\node {a};}
\tikz[baseline=-4ex]{\node {a};}
for a dance.

\end{document}
```

or use a node as in the linked question.

I have specified dimensions in terms of `ex` and `em` units which reflect the size of the font used, rather than absolute units such as `cm`.