# Double arrow for inline diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows

I want to make a diagram like `A--->B`, but there are two arrows, one written `f_1` and another with `f_2`.

I tried `\stackrel`, but this gives arrows with different sizes.

If using `\mathop{}_{under}^{over}`, then the vertical separation is too large.

I also tried `tikz`, but the height position does not match the inline text.

Edit:

My tikz example code

```
\textbf{cokernel} of
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) at (0,0){$A$};
  \node (b) at (1.5,0){$X$};
  \path[->]
  ([yshift=2pt]a.east)edge node[above]{$f_1$}([yshift=2pt]b.west)
  ([yshift=-2pt]a.east)edge node[below]{$f_2$}([yshift=-2pt]b.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Effect:

[image: Effect:]

And no matter how I adjust the y-position of node (a),(b), it just does not move to the right place.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem or what you tried so far. It would also be helpful to see a picture of what you try to accomplish. I can't imagine that much from you description, but it should be possible with TikZ.

Comment: I just edit the question. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks, but i think the result is quite nice, that you have with `TikZ`, so what do you mena by “move to the right place”? In line with the text before?

Comment: Are you looking for http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65932/15925 ?

Comment: ...which would in your case be `baseline=(a.base)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution using `xy`. If you don't need `tikz`...

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\textbf{cokernel} of $\xymatrix{A\ar@<3pt>[r]^{f_1} \ar@<-3pt>[r]_{f_2} & X}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like that arrow tips you can change it using `\xyoption{tips}` on preamble *(or `\usepackage[all,cmtips]{xy}` as suggested by @egreg)* and then change the arrow tip with

```
\SelectTips{cm}{10}$\xymatrix{A\ar@<3pt>[r]^{f_1} \ar@<-3pt>[r]_{f_2} & X}$
```

where `cm` means Computer Modern. You also can use `lu` or `eu`. See the results

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Isn't `\usepackage[all,cmtips]{xy}` better for selecting CM tips?

Comment: @egreg, it could be. I'll edit and insert your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `tikz-cd`, the baseline works well automatically:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\textbf{cokernel} of
\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[yshift=2pt]{r}{f_1} \ar[yshift=-2pt]{r}[swap]{f_2} & X
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Personally, I prefer `tikz-cd` to `xy` because to my eyes, the arrow tips in `xy` are not correctly aligned with the shafts.