# Is there a built in tool in MikTex/TeXworks to output a list of labels used in the current document?

Tags: cross-referencing, miktex, texworks

I was looking for a way to output a list of all the labels used in the document, but so far have only found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15101/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-the-labels-in-a-latex-document-in-winedt) that uses a built in function in WinEdt. Is there a similar functionality in MikTex/TeXworks, or will I need to search the file using one of the regular expression and running it in command prompt or something? I'm currently using TeXworks Version 0.6.1 (MikTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit) on Windows 10. Thanks!

Comment: you can easily extract that from the .aux file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok, I see it in the .aux file now; didn't know it was there. Would the solution be to just search through the file then? I was looking to a way to list just the labels is a different window than the main document to reference as I'm writing.

Comment: I, too, think this constitutes an answer. It's specific to LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on the comment by @DavidCarlisle, I was able to figure out how to search the *.aux file for the labels. First I had to tell TeXworks to show the *.aux file using the instructions found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327666/texworks-not-writing-log-or-aux-files) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113776/ams-tex-with-texworks). Then I was able to use PowerShell to search the contents of the file using the Select-String cmdlet based on the instructions [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/15/powertip-using-powershell-to-search-text-files-for-letter-pattern/) and searching for "label" in the *.aux file.

Comment: If there's a more elegant solution, I'd accept that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this counts as built-in, but you can always let LaTeX do the work for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

% These packages are only used in the example content:
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
    % Just for demonstration purposes
    \def\setcurrentlabelname#1{%
        \def\@currentlabelname{#1}%
    }
    % I use this to format the output.
    % basically taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275957/48973
    \def\flexbox#1#2{%
        {%
            \settowidth{\@tempdima}{#2}%
            \ifdim\@tempdima < #1%
                \makebox[#1][l]{#2}%
            \else
                #2%
            \fi
        }%
    }

    % \newlabel is the command used in the .aux file to register labels
    \let\original@newlabel\newlabel
    \def\newlabel#1#2{%
        \gappto\@labellist{,{{#1}{#2}}}%
        \original@newlabel{#1}{#2}%
    }
    % its format changes when using hyperref
    \ltx@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
        \def\@labellist{{{<label>}{{<num>}{<page>}{<title>}{<anchor>}{<>}}}}%
        \def\@makelabelparameterslist#1#2#3#4#5{%
            {#1}/.1\textwidth,%
            {#2}/.1\textwidth,%
            {#3}/.2\textwidth,%
            {#4}/.2\textwidth,%
            {#5}/.05\textwidth
        }%
    }{%
        \def\@labellist{{{<label>}{{<num>}{<page>}}}}%
        \def\@makelabelparameterslist#1#2{%
            {#1}/.1\textwidth,%
            {#2}/.1\textwidth
        }%
    }
    % for printing the label list to the document
    \def\printlabellist{%
        \clearpage\noindent
        {%
            \small\raggedright
            \def\@print@labelwithinfo##1##2{%
                \@hangfrom{%
                    \flexbox{.2\textwidth}{[\texttt{##1}]}%
                }{%
                    \hskip .025\textwidth
                    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\@makelabelparameterslist ##2}%
                    \foreach \field/\minwidth in \@tempa {%
                        \flexbox{\minwidth}{[\texttt{\field}]}%
                        \hskip .025\textwidth
                    }%
                }\par
            }%
            \foreach \entry in \@labellist {%
                \expandafter\@print@labelwithinfo\entry
            }%
        }%
        \clearpage
    }
    % for writing the label list to the log file and console
    {\catcode`\^^I=11\gdef\@tabchar{^^I}}
    \def\typeoutlabellist{%
        {%
            \def\@typeout@labelwidthinfo##1##2{%
                \message{^^J##1}%
                \expandafter\def\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter{\@makelabelparameterslist ##2}%
                \foreach \field/\minwidth in \@tempa {%
                    \message{\@tabchar\@tabchar\field}%
                }%
            }%
            \message{^^JLabels used in this document:}%
            \foreach \entry in \@labellist {%
                \expandafter\@typeout@labelwidthinfo\entry
            }%
            \message{^^J^^J}%
        }%
    }
\makeatother

% print the label list at the end of the document
\AtEndDocument{\printlabellist}
% also write it to the log file
\AtEndDocument{\typeoutlabellist}

\begin{document}

\section{One}\label{sec:one}
\subsection{Alpha}\label{sec:alpha}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Beta}\label{sec:beta}
\lipsum[2]

\section{Two}\label{sec:two}
\lipsum[3-4]

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Ooh, an image!}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\section{Three}\label{sec:three}
\subsection{Aleph}\label{sec:aleph}
\lipsum[6]

\subsection{Beth}\label{sec:beth}
\lipsum[7]
\begin{equation}\setcurrentlabelname{Fermat's last theorem}\label{eq:fermat}
    \nexists \; a, b, c, n \in \mathbb Z_+, n > 2 : a^n + b^n = c^n
\end{equation}
\lipsum[8]

\subsection{Gimel}\label{sec:gimel}
\lipsum[9]

\end{document}
```

`\printlabellist` outputs a list of the labels in the document (if `hyperref` is not used, only the first three columns exist):

[image: MWE output of the label list]

`\typeoutlabellist` will write the label list to the log file (and the console):

```
Labels used in this document: 
<label>         <num>       <page>      <title>         <anchor>        <> 
sec:one         1       1       One         section.1        
sec:alpha       1.1         1       Alpha       subsection.1.1       
sec:beta        1.2         1       Beta        subsection.1.2       
sec:two         2       1       Two         section.2        
fig:example         1       2       Ooh, an image!      figure.1         
sec:three       3       2       Three       section.3        
sec:aleph       3.1         2       Aleph       subsection.3.1       
sec:beth        3.2         2       Beth        subsection.3.2       
eq:fermat       1       3       Fermat's last theorem       equation.3.1         
sec:gimel       3.3         3       Gimel       subsection.3.3
```

(If anybody knows of a way to better format this table (i.e. pad the short entries with spaces), let me know.)